# Is there any tool to validate my setting on IIS is correct?

Tags: iis

Time to time customers set up the my app on IIS and I had to spent hours to see what he/she did wrong. Sometimes is the path for app or forgot to configure windows authentication properly. Is there any tool that which can validate what is wrong? Or there is any automation tool which can create web site and set configuration automatically?

Comment: You need to automate your releases using Continuous Integration tools if you want to avoid these mistakes..

Comment: I want to find out what kind of tools are available to do that